# Development tools permission I did not set

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I've been creating an android app and when I export (and sign) it, it always adds a "Development tools (test access to protected storage" permission that I had never set.
This is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tdr"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="Escriure"
            android:enabled="true" >
        </activity>
        <activity android:enabled="true" android:name="Llegir"></activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

I do need to write and read files from the external storage, but not to use (¿?) development tools. Where is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: which android version are you using?

Comment: I'm using 4.1.2 Jelly Bean on the testing phone, Gingerbread on the project.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Android has added a new permission that needs to be added for Jelly Bean. Please read this [article](http://www.androidguys.com/2012/06/29/jelly-bean-has-new-permission-option-to-read-external-storage/), which is copied below for quick reference:

> Now, in Jelly Bean, we’re getting the “read external storage”
> permission. According to Google:
>
> **READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE**
>
> Provides protected read access to external
> storage. In Android 4.1 by default all applications still have read
> access. This will be changed in a future release to require that
> applications explicitly request read access using this permission. If
> your application already requests write access, it will automatically
> get read access as well. There is a new developer option to turn on
> read access restriction, for developers to test their applications
> against how Android will behave in the future. So, when you hop into
> the development options on your Jelly Bean device, don’t be surprised
> to see this new option. We won’t see the permission in Android 4.1.0,
> but most likely in 4.1.1, and its intention is to keep your device
> more secure.

Comment: And? Why there's no message that the application requires SD card access?