# App requesting undeclared permission - "Test access to protected storage"

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-permissions

I've added to my `manifest` permission declaration for `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, and after some time I've noticed it asks also for `Test access to protected storage` when installing.
I declare in my `manifest` the `minSdk` as 14 and my `targetSdk` as 19.

How can I get rid of that ?

Comment: What device/emulator are you testing on (in terms of OS version), and how are you installing the APK for that test?

Comment: Using `mako` (Nexus4) with 4.3.1 installed by copying the APK to the "SD CARD" (0 partition)

Comment: Copying the APK to external storage does not install it. So, I will ask again: how are you installing the APK for that test?

Comment: Copying it to SDCARD and running the APK using a file explorer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That prompt would appear to be tied to `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, which you are presumably being given automatically since you requested `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

> How can I get rid of that ?

Remove your `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission. This, of course, has side effects. :-)

Comment: Should it stay if ill declare `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` , since it does, and then I really can't understand it. (Since only `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` would have displayed another permission request)

Comment: @SagiLow: "Since only READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE would have displayed another permission request" -- and you have requested `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, by virtue of requesting `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. Quoting [the documentation for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE): "Any app that declares the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission is implicitly granted this permission".

Answer (score 3):

You have to be more specific. Setting `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission also sets `Test access to protected storage` as this is a sub permission. I believe there is no way around this. Also you can see here: [Development tools permission I did not set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534843/development-tools-permission-i-did-not-set)

Comment: I need the write permission to write a backup of my `sharedPreferences`, whats the idea of having 2 permissions for 1 declaration ?

Comment: Please see here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html and don't forget to mark my answer as correct.

Comment: Well, I cant see how you asking me to be more specific and sending me to a page with the complete list of permissions helps me. I looked on the list and it seems I do request the correct permission. Thanks for your time but it's not yet an answer.