# Android dev, disable Development Tools permission

Tags: android, permissions, manifest

My app is asking for the permission Development tools test access to protected area storage, like it is described here: [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534843/development-tools-permission-i-did-not-set)
 
 Is there any way to prevent my app to ask for this permission:

[image: permission]

My client does not like this message and it is almost impossible to persuade him that it's no harm and should not worry about it. So, What could i do to prevent it showing up?

Answer (score 0):

This message comes from the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission.You may be using these in menifest.

Comment: What you're saying makes sense. But according to android documentation it is enforced: 

> This permission is enforced starting in API level 19. Before API level 19, this permission is not enforced and all apps still have access to read from external storage. You can test your app with the permission enforced by enabling Protect USB storage under Developer options in the Settings app on a device running Android 4.1 or higher.

I really think now that there is now way to prevent this for sure on newer devices. It's up to the user's settings.